# How to scrape same class name data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some real estate websites but the one I came across has same class name under one div and that div has also 2 more div which has same class name. I want to scrape child class data (I think).

I want to scrape below class data:

```
<div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">New Property</div>
```

Below is the whole block of code I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div class="m-srp-card__collapse js-collapse" aria-collapsed="collapsed" data-container="srp-card- 
   summary">
   <div class="m-srp-card__summary js-collapse__content" data-content="srp-card-summary">   
   <input type="hidden" id="propertyArea42679361" value="888 sqft">
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">carpet area</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">888&nbsp;sqft</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">status</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">Ready to Move</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">floor</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">9 out of 13 floors</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">transaction</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">New Property</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">furnishing</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">Unfurnished</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">facing</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">South -West</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">overlooking</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">Garden/Park, Main Road</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">society</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">
        <a id="project-link-42679361" class="m-srp-card__summary__link" 
        href="https://www.magicbricks.com/skylights-bopal-ahmedabad-pdpid-4d4235303936323633" 
        target="_blank">Skylights</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">car parking</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">1 Covered</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">bathroom</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">balcony</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">ownership</div>
        <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">Co-operative Society</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-srp-card__collapse__control js-collapse__control" data-toggle="list-collapse" 
     data-target="srp-card-summary" onclick="stopPage=true;">
  <div class="ico m-srp-card__ico">
  <svg role="icon">
   <use xlink:href="#icon-caret-down"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I tried Indexing but got nothing.

Below is my code:

```
req = Request('https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa&Locality=Bopal&cityName=Ahmedabad', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'm-srp-card__desc flex__item'})
container = containers[0]
no_apartment = container.find('h3').find('span', {'class': 'm-srp-card__title__bhk'}).getText()
c_area = container.find('div', {'class': 'm-srp-card__summary__info'}).getText()
p_price = container.find('div', {'class': 'm-srp-card__info flex__item'})
p_type = container.find('div', {'class': 'm-srp-card__summary js-collapse__content'})[3].find('div', {'class': 'm-srp-card__summary__info'})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not the place to dump off your work for others to do.

Comment: I edited the code!

Comment: So what's the issue with the code, exactly?

Comment: I want to scrape this( <div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">New Property</div> ) line of code but other line have also same class name under one big div class.

Comment: Where are the siblings which both have that same class? I glanced at the HTML source but I can't find them.

Comment: parent class(<div class="m-srp-card__summary js-collapse__content" data-content="srp-card-summary">),which has multiple child class(<div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">) and these child class has two siblings. However I only want information from this(<div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">transaction</div>) sibling.

Comment: Alright, I found`<div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">transaction</div>` and `<div class="m-srp-card__summary__info">New Property</div>`. What's the problem? Your post doesn't mention much about the format of the HTML, by the way. It would be good to have that information, since right now we don't know which parts of the structure will be consistent across the different pages.

Comment: @VinitPanchal Do you want to scrap all data from the `<div class="m-srp-card__summary__item">` that contains `<div class="m-srp-card__summary__title">` with the string `transaction`?

Comment: @VinitPanchal check my answer below

Comment: showing an example output row would help make it clearer what you wish to scrape and the output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa&Locality=Bopal&cityName=Ahmedabad')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

category = []
size = []
price = []
floor = []
for item in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'm-srp-card__title__bhk'}):
    category.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
for item in soup.findAll(text=re.compile('area$')):
    size.append(item.find_next('div').text)
for item in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'm-srp-card__price'}):
    price.append(item.text)
for item in soup.findAll(text='floor'):
    floor.append(item.find_next('div').text)
data = []
for items in zip(category, size, price, floor):
    data.append(items)

with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Category', 'Size', 'Price', 'Floor'])
    writer.writerows(data)
    print("Operation Completed")
```

View Output Online: [click here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=902e181e681d2ee093d789979ebbcdcd8c931fa31086fefb80952f7a20715d4585bb4e72fd1d3146e2f3e5e40a0944a3833cc3b7c53298218b273b27d4ce0c9f)

Comment: The for-loops are not necessary. '.findAll()' creates an array right away.